Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'
I tried changing the Kotlin version since mine wasn't compatible with the compiler, as suggested in the error, i changed the version from 1.9.0 to 1.8.10, but then i received an error which stated Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.8.10.
Error message
code where i changed the version
I suspect the issue may stem from the modified version, but I'm not entirely sure. To provide more clarity, I'll include the Gradle dependencies below. Since I'm new to Kotlin, I appreciate any help.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.8.10"
    }
}


android {
    namespace = "com.example.beyondar_kotlin"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.beyondar_kotlin"
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)



    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.20")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    val cameraxVersion = "1.3.0-rc01"

    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:$cameraxVersion")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$cameraxVersion")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$cameraxVersion")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-video:$cameraxVersion")

    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:$cameraxVersion")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-extensions:$cameraxVersion")

    implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.4.0")
    implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu-delegate-plugin:0.4.0")
    implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.9.0")
}


There are multiple build.gradle.kts files and a settings.gradle.kts file that make up the build configuration for an Android project. You are also using a version catalog, probably located in a file at gradle/libs.versions.toml. All of these parts may be required to check that you've changed the version correctly and to pinpoint how to fix it.
